# How do I get the last occurrence and display the rest?

Tags: php, explode

I would like to know how to get the last occurrence in my string
and display what came before it, for example:

```
$string = "folder\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6\archive.anyextensionhere";
```

And return:

```
$result = "folder\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6";
```

I tried with explode (explode("\\", $string)) but I couldn't continue. If anyone can help me I appreciate.

[UPDATE]

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using an array.

```
$array = array("hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Episódios [BD 720p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_01 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [070B7F17].mkv","hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Episódios [BD 720p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_02 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [F4746E93].mkv","hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Ovas [DVD 480p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [288FC3D3].mkv","hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Ovas - Kuinaki Sentaku [DVD 480p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin - Kuinaki Sentaku_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [19570EA3].mkv");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode on the string, and then remove the last element and then implode again like so:

```
<?php 
$string = "folder\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6\archive.anyextensionhere";
$array = explode('\\', $string);
$file = array_pop($array);
$new_string = implode("\\", $array);
```

This will first split the string into an array by taking each part between slashes, then it will put the last element of the array in the `$file` variable, after doing that it will remove the last element of the array and finally turn the array back into a string

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @user3413650 if this fixes your problem, please click the checkbox marking this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's function `pathinfo` and it will return all you need in an array.

Using pathinfo gives you `[dirname], [basename], [extension] and [filename]` which I believe is all the info you are requesting for :)

Using your data as an example:

```
<pre>
    <?php
    $array = array("hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Episódios [BD 720p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_01 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [070B7F17].mkv","hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Episódios [BD 720p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_02 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [F4746E93].mkv","hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Ovas [DVD 480p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [288FC3D3].mkv","hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Ovas - Kuinaki Sentaku [DVD 480p]\[Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin - Kuinaki Sentaku_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [19570EA3].mkv");

        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            print_r (pathinfo ($arr));
        }
    ?>
</pre>
```

return

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\EpisÃ³dios [BD 720p]
    [basename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_01 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [070B7F17].mkv
    [extension] => mkv
    [filename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_01 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [070B7F17]
)
Array
(
    [dirname] => hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\EpisÃ³dios [BD 720p]
    [basename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_02 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [F4746E93].mkv
    [extension] => mkv
    [filename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_02 [BD 720p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [F4746E93]
)
Array
(
    [dirname] => hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Ovas [DVD 480p]
    [basename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [288FC3D3].mkv
    [extension] => mkv
    [filename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [288FC3D3]
)
Array
(
    [dirname] => hacc_snk720\[Hacchi Fansub] Shingeki no Kyojin [BD 720p] + Ovas [Completo]\Ovas - Kuinaki Sentaku [DVD 480p]
    [basename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin - Kuinaki Sentaku_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [19570EA3].mkv
    [extension] => mkv
    [filename] => [Hacchi Fansub]_Shingeki no Kyojin - Kuinaki Sentaku_OVA 01 [DVD 480p][H264 AAC 8 Bits] [19570EA3]
)
```

Comment: In this case will not work for that I'm using an array, I forgot to tell you, I'm sorry, but I updated the topic with more information.

Comment: Your code is not working see here https://eval.in/791584 make it correct before someone come and downvote your post.